# Using React Hooks to update location give error: Error while updating 'region' of a view managed by: AIRMAP

Tags: react-native, geolocation, react-hooks

I have this error, I can't figure out what went wrong. I'm using React Hooks(useState and useEffect) to update the current location of a user in a react native app.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import MapView, {PROVIDER_GOOGLE} from 'react-native-maps';
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';

const MapScreen = () => {
   const [location, setLocation] = useState({
latitude: 18.9712,
longitude: -72.2852,
latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
 });

useEffect(() => {
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
  const region = {
    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
    longitude: position.coords.longitude,
    latitudeDelta: 0.001,
    longitudeDelta: 0.001,
  }
  setLocation({region})
})

}, [])
return (
<MapView
  provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
  style={{flex: 1}}
  showsUserLocation={true}
  region={location}

/>
)
}

export default MapScreen
```

Comment: I think issue is here `setLocation({region})`. Try this `setLocation(region)`

Comment: That's right, please add the answer so I can accept it as the correct answer instead of just a comment. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is here,

```
setLocation({region})
```

here `region` is an object, so it becomes

```
setLocation({{
    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
    longitude: position.coords.longitude,
    latitudeDelta: 0.001,
    longitudeDelta: 0.001,
}})
```

**which is incorrect setState.**

You just need to set region,

```
setLocation(region)
```